# In Backbone.js, after I perform a collection.fetch({'add':true}), how do I get the latest elements retrieved?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I called fetch, and it hits the server.

Now...my server returns models back...how can I get those just-added models?

Answer (score 1):

the [fetch](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch) method has a success callback with the following signature:

```
success: function(collection, response){

}
```

the `collection` argument is your collection with the newly added models as well as whatever was there previously.  `response` is the json response from the server.  So you could look up the models in `collection` using the ids from `response` to get the 'just-added models'.